# CosmosDB output binding not updating database

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

In a TypeScript functions project, I built an HTTP triggered function that reads item data from CosmosDB using and input binding and tries to update the items using an output binding.

The expected flow is:

HTTP trigger -> function execution & read item from DB via input binding -> update or create item via output binding -> return HTTP response (JSON)

Function code:

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
    context: Context,
    req: HttpRequest,
    productItem: any,
    productToUpdate: any
): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    
    productToUpdate = JSON.stringify({
        "id" : productItem.id,
        "name" : "Changed by output binding"
    })
    
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: {
            id: context.bindingData.productId,
            name: "Updated product"
        }
    };

};
```

If I trigger the function at `/api/products/1234` it will execute correctly and `productItem` is read from my DB and contains the item information with ID "1234":

[image]

The change to `productToUpdate` however, has no effect. The DB content remains unchanged. I tried to use both `JSON.stringify()` and a plain object `{ "id": ... }`.

There is no error message and no indication about a failing operation.
What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this issue?

For reference, here's my binding information in function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "product/{productId}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "productItem",
      "databaseName": "maindb",
      "collectionName": "products",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDbConnectionString",
      "id": "{productId}",
      "partitionKey": "{productId}"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "productToUpdate",
      "databaseName": "maindb",
      "collectionName": "products",
      "createIfNotExists": "false",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDbConnectionString"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/products/index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after some trying. There are different ways to work with bindings. These are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#bindings) in the JavaScript docs for Azure Functions.
The part about ["output" bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#outputs) is relevant for this case:

> [Recommended for multiple outputs] Returning an object. If you are
>   using an async/Promise returning function, you can return an object
>   with assigned output data. In the example below, the output bindings
>   are named "httpResponse" and "queueOutput" in function.json.

And an example is given where an HTTP triggered function returns a response *and* updates a queue item. For my scenario, the return statement would have to look like this:

```
return {
    res : {
        status: 200,
        body: {
            id: context.bindingData.productId,
            name: "Updated product"
        }
    },
    productToUpdate : {
        "id": productItem.id,
        "name": "Updated by TS client " + Date.now()
    }
}
```

Out of the box, this doesn't work for the TypeScript version because the TS function returns `Promise<void>`. This must be changed to `Promise<any>`.

I also recommend to not rely on parameter mapping for bindings and use `context.bindings` instead. Bindings are mapped to the parameters in the **order** they appear in function.json (binding names don't matter). However, **output** bindings cannot be successfully mapped - or beter: they are mapped, but setting them has no effect in async functions. To avoid confusion, I think relying on `context.bindings` for **all** of the bindings is a better option.

Comment: I hit this same issue, but I'm still a bit confused on the implementation.  Can you post the full working solution code? Would be much appreciated!